# Group_by and mutate by multiple columns in R

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I have dataframe with country, gender, 2013,2014,2014,2015 column names.

```
City           Gender  2013  2014  2015
Aberdeen       Female   30    40    50
Aberdeen       Male     20    15    16
Aberdeenshire  Female   60    80    70
Aberdeenshire  Male     50    40    15
.....Includes 425 records.
```

I want to perform female to male ratio (dividing Female/male for each city) for each city, so this is how i tried to get,

```
City           2013_ratio  2014_ratio  2015_ration
Aberdeen        1.5        2.66        2.5
Aberdeenshire   1.2        2           4.66
```

can anyone help me to solve this. I have tried grouping by city but I don't know how to do by getting value by rows in gender.

Comment: Transform the DF into a long DF using gather(). Then you can group_by(City, Year) and calculate the ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code from Rob's suggested solution would be (with an additional `spread()` step:

```r
# data
df = data.frame(City = c("a", "a", "b", "b"),
                Gender = c("Female", "Male", "Female", "Male"),
                `2013` = c(30, 20, 60, 50),
                `2014` = c(40, 15, 80, 40),
                `2015` = c(50, 16, 70, 15))

# Actual process
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")
df %>%
    # Transform wide table into tidy
    gather("Year", "Number", X2013:X2015) %>%
    # Reshape gender columns for easier summaries
    spread("Gender", "Number") %>%
    # Compute ratios
    group_by(City, Year) %>%
    summarise(ratio = Female/(Male + Female))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#> # Groups:   City [?]
#>   City  Year  ratio
#>   <fct> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1 a     X2013 0.6  
#> 2 a     X2014 0.727
#> 3 a     X2015 0.758
#> 4 b     X2013 0.545
#> 5 b     X2014 0.667
#> 6 b     X2015 0.824
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

To get exactly your result you can apply back the function `spread()` to spread the ratios over years, (`spread(Year, ratio)`)

Comment: Thank you it gives me the exact answer. I have used this command at last to get minimum ration in the year 2013. female_ratio <- female_ratio %>% spread("Year","ratio")

Answer (score 2):

You can more easily calculate the ratio if the Male and Female are in different columns, which you can change the structure by using `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  gather(Year, Value, -City, - Gender) %>% 
  spread(Gender, Value) %>% 
  mutate(Ratio = Female/Male, Year = paste0(Year, "_Ratio")) %>% 
  select(-Female, -Male) %>% 
  spread(Year, Ratio)
```

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse`:

```
 df = read.table(text="City           Gender  2013  2014  2015
 Aberdeen       Female   30    40    50
 Aberdeen       Male     20    15    16
 Aberdeenshire  Female   60    80    70
 Aberdeenshire  Male     50    40    15", header = T)
> library(tidyverse)
> 
> df %>%
   group_by(City) %>%
   arrange(City, Gender) %>%
   summarise_at(vars(X2013:X2015), .funs = funs(ratio = first(.)/last(.)))
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  City          X2013_ratio X2014_ratio X2015_ratio
  <fct>               <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1 Aberdeen              1.5        2.67        3.12
2 Aberdeenshire         1.2        2           4.67
```

or

```
df %>%
  group_by(City) %>%
  arrange(City,Gender) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(X2013:X2015), .funs = funs(ratio = .[Gender == "Female"]/.[Gender != "Female"]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Is that possible to get which city has most changing ratio and which is least?